# Jquery, si es undefined. devolver null o vacio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola puedo hacer que si el valor es `undefined` me devuelva `null` o bien vacio??

Estoy probando así pero no hace nada:

```
            if(index == 1)
            {
            var td = {};
            td["dato"+index] = $(this).find(".laOpcion option:selected").val();
            if(td["dato"+index] == 'undefined'){
                td["dato"+index] = null;
                return td["dato"+index];
            }
            tr.push(td);
            }
```

Comment: Si pones esto: `== 'undefined'` parece que indicas que esperas la variable sea igual  a un string que diga undefined, ¿has probado sin comillas?

Comment: Si he probado, pero no me devuelve nada y necesito un null @BetaM , pasa de devolverme undefined a saltarse la linea

Answer (score 2):

Para verificar si una variable es `undefined`, sin que de error si la variable no existe:

```
if (typeof variable === 'undefined') {
```

Para verificar si la propiedad de un objeto es `undefined`:

```
if (objeto.propiedad === undefined) {
```

En tu caso (con `===` y sin comillas):

```
if (td["dato"+index] === undefined) {
```

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta @Pollo , al hacerlo así no me imprime la linea, la salta

Comment: @Miguel no veo que estés imprimiendo nada en tu código... quizás el `return` te esté trayendo problemas... Esta es la forma de verificar si es `undefined`... Si estás teniendo OTRO problema en el código, perfectamente podés publicar una nueva pregnuta

Answer (score 1):

El `null` tal cual en Javascript puede ser interpretado por falsy y por lo general Javasscript lo convierte precisamente `undefined`, no entiendo muy bien por que si es `undefined` quieres asignar a un valor que YA es `undefined`

Podrías intentar esto

```
if (index == 1) {
    var td = {};
    td["dato" + index] = $(this).find(".laOpcion option:selected").val();
    if ( !td["dato" + index] ) {
        return td["dato" + index];
    }
    tr.push(td);
}
```

También podrías usarlo así en caso que necesites controlar el [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) interpretado por Javascript

```
if ( typeof td["dato" + index] === 'undefined' ) {
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Hola @AlbertoSiurob , gracias por tu respuesta. Quiero evaluarlo por que es campo puede ir vacio entonces cuando llega  al controlador lo compruebo, si viene vacio no hago nada, de este modo como viene `undefinde` me devuelve error como que no existe

Comment: El controlador, dependiendo del lenguaje puede ser evaluado de distintas formas. Yo diría que tu problema no es JS, si no como evalúas la información en el back.

Comment: Estoy en laravel, asi que es en php, entonces lo evaluo así: `if(!is_null($arraySingle['dato1'])) {`

Comment: Yo utilizaría en su lugar `if( !empty( $arraySingle['dato1'] ) ){}` Pero esto ya es tema de otro hilo, reitero, siento que tu problema es de interpretación de back y no de front. Te recomiendo elijas alguna respuesta ya dada o esperes si alguien más te oferta otra respuesta.

Comment: Tienes razón parece más del controlador el problema, voy a publicar otra pregunta, gracias